# Selenium Webdriver - How to click on ''Update icon'' in a grid table

Tags: java, selenium

This is the code to click on 'Update icon' of a specific record from grid view using selenium webdriver (JAVA)

I have written the following code to click on 'Update icon' :-(This code is working fine)

```
     //This will count total no of rows in the grid:-

  List<WebElement> count=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvCustomerDetails']/tbody/tr"));
  int totalNoRecords=count.size();
  System.out.println("total no of rows are  "+totalNoRecords);


  //This will find a particular record in a webtable like po name as selenium_testing11selenium_testing12
  WebElement record=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvCustomerDetails']/tbody/tr/following::td[text()='selenium_testing11']"));
  String poName= record.getText();

  //This will verify that if po name is equals to this then only click on Update icon else print the else message
  if(poName.equals("selenium_testing11")){
  WebElement updateBtn=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvCustomerDetails']/tbody/tr/following::td[text()='selenium_testing11']/preceding-sibling::td//a[contains  (@id,'btnUpdate')]"));
  updateBtn.click();
  }
  else
      System.out.println("Po does not exists");
```

Comment: What error are you getting ? Please share

Comment: you can try with xpath to locate specific row update button element and click on it.

Comment: I want to click on update icon of a specific PO "selenium_testing11". When I am using id of that update icon than i am able to click on it but I need it should click on update icon of a PO name which i am passing.  I don't know how to do it.

Comment: give some words if my answer work, or you have question on my code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
String xpath = "//table[contains(@id, 'gvCustomerDetails')]" + 
"//tr[@class][td[5][text()='%s']]/td[2]/a";

public void clickEditIcon(String po) {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(String.format(xpath, po))).click();
}
```

xpath explain:

`//table[contains(@id, 'gvCustomerDetails')]`  to locator the table 
 `//tr[@class]` means only find rows which is not the header column row 
 `[td[5][text()='%s']]` is a qualifier on tr to say only find tr whose 5th
      cell's text equal to the argument:po,  `td[5]` means the column: PO 
  `/td[2]` means to find the 2th cell(update icon inside it) from matched row
  `/a` means to find the update icon link inside matched cell

Comment: Please explain your code; code-only answers are frowned upon on SO.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but this code is not working for me. @yong

Comment: Hi, i notice that but still its not working. I am using TestNG. I think xpath is not correct.

Comment: If xpath not correct, selenium should throw NoSuchElement exception, did you see it when you runn?  Did you try the xpath in my answer manually in browser dev tool, to see it can find element or not,  Please replace %s in xpath with a real text from  column: PO, before you try manually.

Comment: another possible is that table need time to complete loading. so trying add sleep() for 10 seconds before click().

Comment: @yong I have updated the code. I have find the xpath of same and now its working fine.